# Open-source TextWrangler alternative?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, text-editor

I need to use a text editor that is capable of always saving documents using Windows CRLF line endings. So now I'm using TextWrangler. I am opening files from volumes encrypted with TrueCrypt, and I need the content, and the fact that I'm opening these files, to remain secret.

TextWrangler, on the other hand, conveniently stores information about all documents opened in a file called 'Document State.plist'. The file is XML.

TextWrangler's manual says the following about 'Document State.plist', and nothing else:

"*TextWrangler stores state information for individual documents in this file.*"

There is no way to disable the storing of this information in the preferences. Furthermore, there is a  section for some files that is ASCII encoded, but I don't know what is stored in this field.

So my question is, are there any good open source text editors for Mac that allow you to specify line endings, or is there a way to prevent TextWrangler from creating this file?

Comment: emacs will do the line endings - however why use CRLF most Windows editors can deal with pal CR

Comment: vim or textmate

Comment: As written it's unclear whether you would prefer answers on preventing state getting written or on alternative editors, which makes it difficult to answer this question in an acceptable way. The editor question has come up before on this site so you might even find an existing answer to help you.

Answer (score 0):

TextMate is a good editor on its own right, and has been [open-sourced](https://github.com/textmate) with an active development community.